# PHP Laravel application composer install error

Tags: php, laravel, github, composer-php

I'm new to Laravel. I am trying to download this project and build from git(https://github.com/johndavedecano/PHPLaravelGymManagementSystem). But i am getting the below error when i run `composer install` from cmd.

[image: PHP LARAVEL ERROR]

I'm using XAMPP on windows.

Comment: First run composer dump-autoload then try to install composer install..

Answer (score 0):

It's permission issue, your project **vendor** folder read/write permission add

Comment: No, it's not. It's because artisan is trying to use composer before it has installed deps.

Comment: so whats the resolution ?

Comment: I dont have a vendor folder in the project either